# SecurityError: Error #2122: Security sandbox violation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flickr

I've a `Loader` that loads a Flickr image, then I `draw()` the content of the `Loader`.

I get this error:

> SecurityError: Error #2122: Security sandbox violation:
>   LoaderInfo.content: mywebsite/myswf.swf cannot access flickr/imageurl.
>   A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set
>   when this media was loaded.  at flash.display::LoaderInfo/get
>   content()

The **corssdomain.xml** is loaded from Flickr, I did set `checkPolicyFile` to `true` for a `LoaderContext` that I pass as the 2nd parameter to the `load()` method.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is similar to facebook pictures loading from actionscript as described here http://novacoders.blogspot.com/2011/04/loading-pictures-from-facebook.html

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've figured out the problem. I was loading all the images from static.flickr.com and that's where the crossdomain file came from. That url gave a 302 response status and the images were actually coming from farmX.static.flickr.com. Now I've just changed the flickr url to farm4.static.flickr.com and everything is fine.

Comment: I usually add farm1 through 4 to my applications: I'm not sure whether it's ever the case that images move between farms, but it makes things more flexible either way.